# Sharing utility objects between domain and repository

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, domain-driven-design, repository

I'm currently building a framework that uses a `MySQL` database. I can't use the `MySQL` implementation of the entity framework, so I'm trying to figure out the best way of generalising search and paging functionality.

The simplest solution would be to have repository methods with signatures such as:

```
IList<Blah> GetSomething(string _query, 
                         int _page, 
                         int _pageSize, 
                         out int _numPages)
```

but this seems slightly anti-OOD.

An idea I had was to create a utility dll with an `ISearchParameter` and an `IPaging` object that both the domain level and repository level could access, this would avoid having to recreate these two interfaces and implimentations of them in each domain and repository.

```
public interface ISearchParameters
{
    Direction Direction { get; set; }
    string DirectionField { get; set; }
    string Query { get; set; }
    IList<string> SearchFields { get; set; }
}

public interface IPaging
{
    int CurrentPage { get; set; }
    int PageSize { get; set; }
    int NumberOfPages { get; set; }

    int GetQueryPage();
}
```

I'd usually map DTOs from the repositories to domain objects, but if both levels referenced this utility .dll, would it be bad design to pass ISearchParameter objects between these two levels without mapping? If so, are there any better solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use the Repository Pattern to abstract away your interaction with data access layer.
2. Use an Inversion of Control container to create your repository, to avoid a reference from your domain to data access layer.
3. The data access can then hold a reference to your domain classes, or to the domain class factories--avoiding the need for DTOs (following the DRY principle).
4. Design your interfaces to be stateless.  When crossing layers (which may become tiers), think of services instead of objects.  This would prefer the simpler approach.
5. Avoid having a utility.dll. You really only need to share your repository interfaces between your domain and data access layer.  You could put those in your domain assembly, or better, a separate assembly.

Comment: Hi afeygin, the framework I'm building uses the principles you mention in points 1, 2 and 4. Currently, my data access factory is self contained and only referenced by repositories. The repositories populated DTOs which were mapped to BOs in the domain layers, which again were mapped to Models in the MVC site for consumption by views. Should the repositories actually be pushing out domain classes? I thought this would create coupling between layers? This is an area I've got a lot to learn within, and everyone seems to have their own opinions on what is best!

Comment: Mr Jingo: there is a tradeoff between coupling and DRY.  It depends on your application.  If your application has an SOA architecture (and very few do), you have to use DTOs.  It wouldn't be my first choice.  Not following DRY will make your application brittle and difficult to change, and you want to avoid it as much as you can.  Your domain objects are the heart of your system.  If you design them and manage their lifecycles carefully, and have them serializable, avoid holding too many references, they can serve as the DTOs, the Business Entities, and MVC or MVVM models all in one.

Comment: I guess what I was trying to say--yes, it's ok for repositories to push out domain objects.  And yes, it is coupling, but I've yet to see this a problem in production system.  However I've seen countless of applications paralyzed gradually over time due to brittleness introduced by not following DRY as the number of entities grows.  Remember that intentional coupling is NOT a bad thing.  It's unintentional coupling that you need to avoid.

Comment: Hey afeygin, thanks for taking the time to reply! I'll have a play with your suggestions and see how it goes. I have a final question: if domains use IOC to create the repositories, and the repositories link to the domain to generate domain objects, wouldn't this create circular dependencies? Or should the domain object interfaces be pushed out to their own dll referenced both by the repository and the domains?

Comment: Mr Jingo: this will not create circular references if your repository interfaces are in a separate dll from the repository implementation.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion this is a perfectly suitable solution. In my projects I use jqGrid a lot, which ofcourse also has search, ordering and paging. I use a gridParameters object (defined in my infrastructure layer), which is passed from the controller (UI) to the business layer and the data layer.
The objects don't contain any business rules, so i don't see any problems with this approach.